# Conditional validator in cakephp modelless form

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i need to do the following conditional validation in my modelless form:

```
class NewForm extends Form
{
    if (address_type == 'Street')
        required: street_name, street_type
        not required: po_box
    elseif (address_type == 'PO')
        required: po_box
        not required: street_name, street_type
}
```

I have tried the following validator:

```
$validator
        ->requirePresence('street_name', true, 'street_name is a required field')
        ->notEmpty('street_name', 'street_name is a required field', function ($context) {
            return ($context['address_type'] == 'Street Address');
        })
        ->requirePresence('street_type', true, 'street_type is a required field')
        ->notEmpty('street_type', 'street_type is a required field', function ($context) {
            return ($context['address_type'] == 'Street Address');
        });

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('po_box', true, 'po_box is a required field')
        ->notEmpty('po_box', 'po_box is a required field', function ($context) {
            return ($context['address_type'] == 'PO');
        });
```

When i call validate like such

```
$valid = $newform->validate($data);
```

It requires ALL street_name, street_type, and po_box to be in the input data.

How do i structure the conditional validator to accomplish the pseudocode ?
Thanks

**Edit**

I've come up with the following, which works ! However, it does not allow me get the fields that are empty/invalid from the ->errors()
Ie, i need to be able to know that, for eg, 'street_name' was empty and needs to be filled in.

```
$validator
        ->add('address_type', 'missing fields', [
            'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
                if ($value == 'Street') {
                    if ((!array_key_exists('street_name', $context['data']) && empty($context['data']['street_name'])) ||
                        (!array_key_exists('street_type', $context['data']) && empty($context['data']['street_type']))) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } elseif ($value == 'PO') {
                    if ((!array_key_exists('po_box', $context['data']) && empty($context['data']['po_box'])) ||
                        (!array_key_exists('po_no', $context['data']) && empty($context['data']['po_no'])) ||
                        (!array_key_exists('po_exchange', $context['data']) && empty($context['data']['po_exchange']))) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would come handy if `Validator::requirePresence()` would support callables for conditional evaluation, just like `add()`, `allowEmpty()` and `noteEmpty()` do.

Until something like this is added, there are various other ways to handle this, like for example modifying validators in a custom rule for your `address_type` field, in an overriden `Form::validate()` method, or even in the controller.

I'd probably go with the first variant, something like this, which sets the fields to be required depending on the required `address_type` value:

```
protected function _buildValidator(Validator $validator)
{
    return $validator
        ->requirePresence('address_type')
        ->add('address_type', 'valid', [
            'rule' => function($value) {
                switch ($value) {
                    case 'Street Address':
                        $this->validator()
                            ->requirePresence('street_name')
                            ->requirePresence('street_type');
                        break;

                    case 'PO':
                        $this->validator()
                            ->requirePresence('po_box');
                        break;

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        ])
        ->notEmpty('street_name')
        ->notEmpty('street_type')
        ->notEmpty('po_box')
        // ...
        ;
}
```

**Update**

Support for callables in `requirePresence()` has been [**added for 3.1.1**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/7453). With that functionality it's possible to conditionally require fields like

```
$validator
    // ...
    ->requirePresence('street_name', function ($context) {
        return $context['data']['address_type'] === 'Street Address';
    })
    // ...
    ;
```

To DRY up things in case of many fields one could for example make of use dynamic callable arguments like

```
$requiredFor = function ($value) {
    return function ($context) use ($value) {
        return $context['data']['address_type'] === $value;
    };
};

$validator
    // ...
    ->requirePresence('street_name', $requiredFor('Street Address'))
    ->requirePresence('street_type', $requiredFor('Street Address'))
    ->requirePresence('po_box', $requiredFor('PO'))
    // ...
    ;
```

See also **[Cookbook > Validation > Conditional Validation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#conditional-validation)**

Comment: @yoyoma Not yet, but it shouldn't be too long until it's released. If you're adventurous you can try `dev-master` till 3.1.1 is released.

Comment: until callables for `requirePresence()` is available, the first solution works well, until I need to set one of those fields to null.  Ie, if 'Street Address', the `notEmpty` in that spot means i cannot set 'po_box' to null.  If I move the `notEmpty` into the `switch` area, then it does allow setting of null, however, upon errors, the `form->errors()` does not give me the specific field that is not set.  Hope that makes sense, if you have any suggestions I really appreciate it